# Adding thumbnail to search results & changing content.php

Tags: search, thumbnails

Looking to discover how to alter my content.php code to add the thumbnail image of the specific posts to my search results located here for example:

https://divesummit.com/?s=suunto&submit=Search

I would like a thumbnail of the featured post’s image listed along with the smaller blurb of the post in the search results.

```
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

by somehow changing content.php I can have it include a small thumbnail along with each search result. My theme already has thumb support I just need help implementing it.

Any help on doing this would be appreciated.

PS. I do have a child theme installed

Answer (score 1):

Use [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/). For example:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `content.php` is a possible way to go.

Start by finding the right place to insert lines similar to this:

```
if (is_search()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

The function [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) will output the image selected as [featured image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) upon editing the post. [`is_search()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/) limits this output to when showing search results.